# what django supported database is best for representing trees or revision history?

Tags: django, database, version-control, nosql, revision-history

I want to avoid representing a version control system for AI models in my postgres DB through django. What NoSQL DB can represent a tree structure and has a Django library?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres supports a tree like data, and there is [a not well supported Django extension called ltree](https://pypi.org/project/django-ltree/) that implements this Postgres data structure, which you can implement by inheriting the extension's TreeModel.